# How to fix sonar issue with Promise inside void returning function in Angular?

Tags: angular, promise, rxjs

I got suggestion from sonar cloud analysis that in below code in #2 place I return Promise instead of void.. that's literally true, but I don't know how to resolve it correctly.

```
private editPersonSubject = new Subject<FormData>();
  private editPersonAction$ = this.editPersonSubject.asObservable()
    .pipe(
      switchMap((form: FormData) => {
      
        return this.personService.edit(form).pipe(
          tap(() => {
            this.notificationService.showMsgSuccess(
              `success_translation`,
              `OK updated person`);
          }),
          catchError(() => this.handleError(
                                                                      // #1
            `error_translation`,
            `Error`)),
          finalize(async () => {
            this.spinner.hide('spinner');
            await this.router.navigate([`admin/standard-profiles/`]); // #2
          })
        );
      }),
      this.mapToPersonProfileFormVm()
    );


// merging 

Vm$ = merge(
    this.editPersonAction$$,
  ).pipe(
    scan((prevVm: StandardPersonProfile, mutationFn: (vm: StandardPersonProfile) => StandardPersonProfile) => mutationFn(prevVm),
      {
        Person: null
      } as StandardPersonProfile
```

second question is how to use promise methods in catch error correctly?

Comment: `async` functions _always_ return promises, so if the callback needs to have `void` return type it can't be `async`.

Comment: First off, do you `subscribe()` to the observable somewhere else in your code ?

Comment: @bob.mazzo
I have few subjects and merge them in vm$ by merge operator <question updated>

Comment: jonrsharpe
so what I can do in that case?